# How to compare custom generic List<> in C#?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I've 2 lists of `class A`, `A` has implemented `Equals(object obj)` and `GetHashCode()` this 2 methods working correctly, code is below.

```
class A
{
    public string TEST 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((A)obj).TEST == this.TEST;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() 
    {
        return this.TEST.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I have 2 list of this class, `firstList = { X1, X2, X3 }` and `secondList = { X1, X2, Y1 }`. When I use `firstList.Except(secondList)` it always return all of elements in firstList and `secondList.Except(firstList)` also return every elements in secondList, as show below.

```
var test1 = firstList.Except(secondList).ToList(); // test1 = all elements of firstList
var test2 = secondList.Except(firstList).ToList(); // test2 = all elements of secondList
```

I want to know how can I solving this problem?

Comment: What is the TEST property for?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Test has no type.

Comment: TEST is string, I've fixed it =)

Comment: `Except` is behaving properly for me based upon your sample class structure. Please post a full example of code that is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the type of your TEST. (The sample code does not work, since your property does not specify a type.) If TEST is a reference type (a class) you have to compare them with Equals instead of "=".

This works:

```
   [TestClass]
   public class UnitTest1 {
      class MyString {
         public MyString(string value) {
            _value = value;
         }
         string _value;
         public override int GetHashCode() {
            return _value.GetHashCode();
         }
         public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            MyString other = obj as MyString;
            if (other != null)
               return other._value == this._value;
            return false;
         }
      }

      [TestMethod]
      public void TestMethod1() {
         List<MyString> list1 = new List<MyString> {
            new MyString("1"),
            new MyString("2"),
         };

         List<MyString> list2 = new List<MyString> {
            new MyString("2"),
            new MyString("3"),
         };

         MyString removed = list1[1];
         var result = list1.Except(list2);
         Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count());
         Assert.IsFalse(result.Contains(removed));
      }
   }
```

Comment: What if TEST is string? can I use obj.TEST == this.TEST ?

Comment: Than it would work since string is something "very special". I changed my sample to string.

Comment: If TEST is string I need to use Equals, == always return false even it hold same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IEquatable<>` interface like this

```
public class Test : IEquatable<Test>
{
    public string result;
    public Test(string result) { this.result = result; }
    public bool Equals(Test other)
    {
        return result.Equals(other.result);
    }
    //No need to override Equals(object obj), GetHashCode()
}
```

then when you check do the following

```
List<Test> FirstTests = ...
List<Test> SecondTests = ...

List<Test> Result = FirstTests.FindAll(delegate(Test item)
{
    return SecondTests.Contains(item);
});
```

For the example given above it works. I just love using anonymous methods.

Comment: Should the result field be public?

Comment: No. The point is that Test acts like a wrapper for a result and since Equals() has access to private members, it should not be public.

Answer (score 0):

lookup lambda expressions and LINQ.